# CGAL: Hole Filling .exe file is stuck

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, point-clouds, cgal

**This is my terminal(result) after running the .exe file.** Click the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKGu8.png) for the terminal.

It doesn't stop or gives an error. It's stuck like this for hours.

I got  my code from here [code](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2hole_filling_example_SM_8cpp-example.html), but this is the [data (.off)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CyH1HYlHWRij3hIfWIw3mVdOoFwARKgD/view?usp=sharing) I used.

Comment: For hole filling I use [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/) with the function `igl::harmonic` ... with this approach it's possible to have tangency continuity on the edge of the hole

Comment: Have a look on this [article](https://erkaman.github.io/posts/hole_filling.html) at the end there's a link with a github repository with working code

Comment: Note that if you have pinched holes, you cannot use what  @MarcoBeninca suggests directly. You need to first preprocess them to split them into well separated holes.

Comment: @MarcoBeninca oww i'll check it out, Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoBeninca Actually, I think you should get something similar if you are using [triangulate_refine_and_fair_hole()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__hole__filling__grp.html#ga19bc0ac51dc9a1ee78c3e7a0d57de47d). What I don't know is if the fairing is able to resolve self-intersections that might be created in the initial filling of the hole in the method described by Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to fill a hole that is too large or that cannot be filled using the 3D Delaunay triangulation search space (which can happen also if you have pinched holes). In CGAL 5.5 (not yet released but available in master), we added the option `do_not_use_cubic_algorithm()` (doc [here](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__hole__filling__grp.html#gad2d3c43bce0ef90a16530478196d7f42)) to not use the cubic search space to fill such holes.

Comment: owww, thank you, i'll check it out.